# Taxonomy shows term ID not term name in Facet API

Tags: search

Im trying to facet by taxonomy fields but I see just the ID, not the name of the term, why?

I'm getting this:

```
3 (76)
4 (35)
176 (7)
167 (6)
177 (5)
168 (4)
5 (2)
163 (1)
7 (1)
```

and it should be

```
Casa (76)
Depto (35)
Duplex (7)
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are your field settings in search api index? You should choose for example Brand » Name instead of Brand » Term ID. Brand = your field.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding, Actually I went to the search api job index, there I selected the fields tab, I am displaying the occupation taxonomy terms with the facet widget, on the search api page here i am not sure where I have to choose the occupation, below there is one occupation name and occupation id, but both are unchecked, when I tried to check one occupation name, all the facets widgets went away.

Comment: I think you need to activate right facet widget in facet tab at search api index. Although you should check how to configure/use facet api. For example: http://webwash.net/tutorials/intro-search-api-part-2-faceted-search

Answer (score 2):

in

```
  admin/config/search/facets/your_facet_name/edit
```

you must select :

```
  List item label
 Translate entity label
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you delete terms that are associated with nodes.

Read this long discussion on Drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/1421378